# How can I allow .PDF, .XFC and .GIMP to get uploaded?

Tags: php

I'm trying to allow certain formats to get uploaded on my website. I am using the GD extension in PHP to manipulate images. I use the call getimagesize() to identify the image type which is returned as the third parameter and compare it against a list of predefined GD IMAGETYPE_* constants like this:

```
$a = getimagesize($img);
$image_type = $a[2];
if (in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM, IMAGETYPE_BMP))) {
    // Do something
}
```

How can I get it to also allow  .PDF, .XCF and .GIMP?

List of formats to allow:

- JPEG
- PNG
- GIF
- TIFF
- BMP
- PDF
- XCF
- GIMP

Comment: So the problem is what?

Comment: Where does IMAGETYPE_JPEG come from, and where does $image_type come from?

Comment: @SashaPachev Isn't IMAGETYPE_JPEG  one of the image types?

Comment: @developerwjk How can I allow pdf, xcf and .gimp?

Comment: What's happening vs what should be happening? Come on, you knew that's what I meant.

Comment: @developerwjk Nothing is "happening", I just want to know how to allow those formats.

Comment: Oh, so now that I've read your mind, the problem is that PDF, XCF, and GIMP are not images that getimagesize works on. Yeah. So maybe look at the file extension of the incoming file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getimagesize() returned an unknown type or fails to read the image altogether, read the first few bytes of the image file, then check to see if the value corresponds to a known magic number (signature) of the additional types.

Here is one magic number reference for basic image types:

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html#Image